# two tablesviews using the same json feed

Tags: ios, iphone, json, uitableview

I have a table view that when you press a cell it takes you to another table view.  it uses the same json feed and im putting the feed in the viewdidload method of both tables.  when you press to go to the next table view its slow to load, im guessing because its loading the feed again.  can i put the json feed in the first table and then carry it to the next so it doesnt need to load it again and if so how do i go about doing this

if anyone can anyone help thanks alot for your time code is below

view did load

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Set Title
self.title = @"Authors";



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI

        NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.how-e.co.uk/test.json"];

        NSLog(@"BLOG URL > %@", blogURL);

        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

        NSLog(@"JSONDATA > %@", jsonData);

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

        NSLog(@"JSONDATA > %@", jsonData);


        self.authors = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];


        self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[authors count]];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    });
```

link to next table view

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Initialize Books View Controller
MTBooksViewController *booksViewController = [[MTBooksViewController alloc] init];
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
// Fetch and Set Author
NSDictionary *search = [searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[booksViewController setAuthor:[search objectForKey:@"name"]];
}else {
    NSDictionary *author = [authors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   [booksViewController setAuthor:[author objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
// Push View Controller onto Navigation Stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:booksViewController animated:YES];

}
```

second table

```
-(void)connect{
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.how-e.co.uk/test.json"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

// Update the UI
NSArray *authors = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];


//NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Books" ofType:@"plist"];
//NSArray *authors = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


for (int i = 0; i < [authors count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *authorDictionary = [authors objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *tempAuthor = [authorDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    if ([tempAuthor isEqualToString:_author]) {

        self.books = [authorDictionary objectForKey:@"Books"];
    }

}
```

}

```
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Initialization
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
self = [super initWithStyle:style];

if (self) {

}

return self;
 }

 #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark View Life Cycle
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Books";

     [self connect];
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 }

 #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Getters and Setters


 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section            {
return [self.books count];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

// Similar to UITableViewCell, but
InnerCell *cell = (InnerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[InnerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}


NSDictionary *book = [self.books objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


[cell.descriptionLabel  setText:[book objectForKey:@"Title"]];
[cell.tlabel  setText:[book objectForKey:@"Title"]];
cell.ticon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[book objectForKey:@"Cover"]];
return cell;


}- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
return [indexPath row] + 100;
 }



 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Initialize Book Cover View Controller
MTBookCoverViewController *bookCoverViewController = [[MTBookCoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTBookCoverViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

// Fetch and Set Book Cover
NSDictionary *book = [self.books objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
UIImage *bookCover = [UIImage imageNamed:[book objectForKey:@"Cover"]];
[bookCoverViewController setBookCover:bookCover];

UIImage *bookCover2 = [UIImage imageNamed:[book objectForKey:@"Cover"]];
[bookCoverViewController setBookCover2:bookCover2];

[bookCoverViewController setBookTag:[book objectForKey:@"Title"]];



// Push View Controller onto Navigation Stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bookCoverViewController animated:YES];
 }



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why parsing the dictionary again in second table . create a custom initializer like

secondpage.h

```
  @property (nonatomic ,retain) NSMutableArray *searchResultarray;
 -(id)initWithSearchResults:(NSMutableArray*)searchResult;
```

and use the recieved array as datasource for the table in

secondpage.m

```
@sythesize searchResultarray= _searchResultarray;
    -(id)initWithSearchResults:(NSMutableArray*)searchResult
{
 if (self = [super init])
{
    _searchResultarray= search;
}
}

#pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section            {
return [self.searchResultarray count];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an NSDictionary property in the second view controller and pass the nsdictionary from the first view like this:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Set Title
self.title = @"Authors";



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI

        NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.how-e.co.uk/test.json"];

        NSLog(@"BLOG URL > %@", blogURL);

        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

        NSLog(@"JSONDATA > %@", jsonData);

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

//Here pass the data to the NSDictionary of the secondViewController
secondViewController.sameDataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dataDictionary];

        NSLog(@"JSONDATA > %@", jsonData);


        self.authors = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];


        self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[authors count]];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    });
```

Comment: tried adding this to the second.h @property NSDictionary *sameDataDictionary; but it says in the first bit  secondViewController.sameDataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dataDictionary]; that says sameDataDictionary not found on object type

Comment: add import "Second.h" to the first view .m file.

Comment: I dont get any errors now but i dont get any results through, the nslog result is null, any advice?

Comment: Have you declared the property in your secondViewController? `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *sameDictionary;`

Comment: i have `MTBooksViewController *booksViewController ;
            booksViewController.sameDataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dataDictionary];` in the first tableview.m then in the second.h i have `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *sameDataDictionary;` and in the second.m i have `@synthesize sameDataDictionary;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Update the UI
    
    NSLog(@"JSONDATA > %@", self.sameDataDictionary);
    
}` really sorry about all this and thanks for your help @Nikos M